# React native app crashes second time on launch

Tags: ios, react-native

I have a very simple react native app but somehow it only manages to launch the app the first time on my Iphone after i built it in Xcode and xCode automatically opens the app on the Iphone but if I then clear the app and click on it myself it crashes on launch screen. Have anyone else experienced this and how is it fixed?

This is the error i get

> Failed : error 0:61 [61] 2018-04-10 11:42:52.055583+0200
>   productionApp[37428:16310299] [] nw_connection_get_connected_socket 13
>   Connection has no connected handler 2018-04-10 11:42:52.055606+0200
>   productionApp[37428:16310299] TCP Conn 0x1c4172f00 Failed : error 0:61
>   [61]

Comment: Debugging the crash is usually easier knowing the error message and seeing code related to it.

Comment: Thank you added the error message to the question

Comment: Still an open [issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10027)